# Strange behavior of Cancel button's ActionSheet

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode4

I'm new in Objective-C, I try to code an iPad App (Objective-C 2.0, Xcode 4.0.1).
I "play" with ActionSheet to understand how it works. In a nib file I put a button binded to my "buttonPressed" method.

I've written this code :

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed
{   
    UIActionSheet *myActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Action Sheet" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Test", nil];

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myActionSheet numberOfButtons]]);
    NSLog([myActionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog([myActionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:1]);
    NSLog([myActionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:2]);

    [myActionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [myActionSheet release];
}
```

This is the NSLog result :

```
2011-04-14 14:52:30.428 TrampManage[3568:207] 3
2011-04-14 14:52:30.429 TrampManage[3568:207] OK
2011-04-14 14:52:30.430 TrampManage[3568:207] Test
2011-04-14 14:52:30.432 TrampManage[3568:207] Cancel
```

But the displayed view is quiet different (cf image : http://www.imagup.com/data/1117452257.html). For the moment, I've one simple question : Why my "Cancel" button doesn't appear ?

Comment: More informations here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760545/action-sheet-doesnt-show-cancel-button-on-ipad

Answer (score 0):

As your tag hints, you are probably working on an ipad project.

The documentation says about the cancel button for iPads:

> **cancelButtonTitle** The title of the
>   cancel button. This button is added to
>   the action sheet automatically and
>   assigned an appropriate index, which
>   is available from the
>   cancelButtonIndex property. This
>   button is displayed in black to
>   indicate that it represents the cancel
>   action. **Specify nil if you do not want
>   a cancel button or are presenting the
>   action sheet on an iPad**.

You can cancel by touching outside the action sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I've already read the ActionSheet Reference documentation, and your bypass suggestion is interesting but... What if I want a CancelButton ?

Comment: use other buttons for it, you'll have to live with with the light background color though.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely on an iPad, where the new interface idiom is to not show the cancel button. A user can cancel the sheet by simply clicking outside the sheet. Not the best design decision IMHO, but that's the way it is now.

Answer (score 0):

on ipad it doesn't shows the cancel button. because ipad has more width than the iphone & for dismiss it you can tab outside the actionsheet on ipad.

Detail explaination:

see this image of iphone which shows ok button 
[image]

> below Figure  shows the action sheet when displayed on the iPad.
>   Interestingly, on the iPad the OK button (set by the
>   cancelButtonTitle: parameter) is not displayed.

[image]

> The value (buttonIndex) of each button when clicked is as follows: 
> ➤
>   Delete Message — 0 
>  ➤ Option 1 — 1
>  ➤ Option 2 — 2
>  ➤ OK
>   — 3
>  On the iPad, when the user taps on an area outside of the
>   action sheet, the action sheet is dismissed and the value of
>   buttonIndex becomes 3. Interestingly, if you specified nil for the
>   cancelButtonTitle: part, the value of buttonIndex would be –1 when the
>   action sheet is dismissed.